# Permissions won't let me view tables on restored SQL Server database in AWS RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I restored a database to AWS RDS with this command:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database 
              @restore_db_name='database_name', 
              @s3_arn_to_restore_from='arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/file_name_and_extension';
```

The problem is that, even though the database looks like it restored, I can't see anything in the actual database.

When I try select statements

```
SELECT * FROM users
```

they produce a permissions denied error. When I try, through Management Studio, to view tables or even expand the database, I get permission errors.

Why does this happen? How do I give my logged in user total access?

Comment: If you're restoring a database then the users within that database will already exist. If the logins exist on your instance already with the same SIDs as the users then they will be mapped to your server logins. On the other hand, if you are using a non-priviledged account to restore the database and you don't have a user mapped on the database, you won't be able to access the underlying information. You'll likely need to log in as a `sysadmin` create a user on the restored database for your login, grant yourself the necessary permissions, and then switch back to your login.

Comment: i'm logging in with the same users that I used on the original db. actually setup a user when i created the rds account there as well. still confused :\

Comment: But do they have the same SID? A user and login haviing the same name does not mean that are mapped to each other.

Comment: more than likely they don't. How do i login as sysadmin? I thought when i first created my rds database, the user it made me create, had admin permissions... is that not the case? If so, how do i change permissions on that user?